# Window.Opener.HREF in IE but not Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I came across this post which I thought would solve my problem: [window.opener.location.href works in IE but not Chrome or Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720061/window-opener-location-href-works-in-ie-but-not-chrome-or-safari)

Unfortunately, my setup is slightly different.

I have a form on a page that contains a link that opens a new window.  That window contains a form that calls an external script on submit.  What I want to do, is when the form on the "popup" window is submitted, is close that popup, and have the original page refresh.

This is what I call in the submit script document, and it works great in IE, where most of the users will be working.  But not all...

```
window.opener.document.location.href='q.php?q=<?php echo $q; ?>&id=<?php echo $id; ?>';
this.window.close();
```

In Chrome, when I don't close the window, I see what is happening.  It seems to be refreshing that popup window with the q.php page.  This makes some sense to me, since the refresh is in the popup's called submit script, but I would prefer to make it act like IE (I can't really believe I said that).  I am not sure how to make the original page refresh (showing the data submitted by the popup submit, and still have that popup close.

I would appreciate any advice.  Thank you